# Want to convert string value to float in spark python

Tags: python, lambda, apache-spark

Hello subject expert please have look and help me got stuck here
I have two files and i combined them using union function is spark. and getting ouptput like.

file1 contains.(u'[12345,  90604080', 0.0)
               (u'[67890,  70806080', 320.0)

file2 contains. (u'[12345,  90604080', 0.0)
                (u'[67890, 70806080', 0.0)

[u"(u'[12345", u"  90604080'", u' 0.0)']
[u"(u'[67890", u"  70806080'", u' 320.0)'] this is combined output [12345", u"  90604080'" is my keys and 0.0 are their values i want to aggregate the values according to the keys and stoared the output into third file. this is my code. like '12345,  90604080',0.0  and 67890,  70806080', 320.0
but Getting following error
ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 70.0)

```
from pyspark import SparkContext

import os

import sys


sc = SparkContext("local", "aggregate")


file1 = sc.textFile("hdfs://localhost:9000/data//part-00000")
file2 = sc.textFile("hdfs://localhost:9000/data/second/part-00000")

file3 = file1.union(file2).coalesce(1).map(lambda line: line.split(','))

result = file3.map(lambda x: ((x[0]+', '+x[1],float(x[2])))).reduceByKey(lambda a,b:a+b).coalesce(1)



result.saveAsTextFile("hdfs://localhost:9000/Test1")
```

thanks for the help

Comment: I don't understand much of what you say, I mean you should really improve the explanation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have an extra closing parenthesis in your string. Try:

```
result = file3.map(lambda x: ((x[0]+', '+x[1],float(x[2][:-1])))).reduceByKey(lambda a,b:a+b).coalesce(1)
```

Clarification:

The error-message tells us that the float-conversion got `70.0)` as argument. What we want is `70.0`. So we just need to omit the last character of the string which we can do with index slicing:

```
>>> a = "70.0)"
>>> a = a[:-1]
>>> print a
"70.0"
```

The last line can be read as `a` is equal to `a` from index 0 to index -1. -1 is equivalent to `len(a)-1`.

Comment: Thanks Aske Doerge. can u explain what u did . and can we remove U' U" suffixes.

Comment: I have added a little explanation now. The `u` before a string denotes that it is unicode in python. However it looks like your data has been saved in a messy way. There are also parts of a list in your string.

Comment: Now (u'[12345, 90604080', 0.0) & (u"(u'[12345,   90604080'", 0.0) for this by applying same result = file3.map(lambda x: ((x[0]+', '+x[1],float(x[2][:-1])))).reduceByKey(lambda a,b:a+b).coalesce(1) transformation i am getting output like  (u"(u'[\12345,   90604080'", 0.0) getting \ somewhere in output.  please put focus on this